# Access token for Sharepoint homepage/frontend

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal

I'm writing an application in C# that needs to access data that is stored on Sharepoint Online. I'm using Microsoft authentication (oauth2) and delegated permissions (the users sign's in when opening the app with his Microsoft account using msal.net library).

I've created an Public

Getting a list with all sites via the Sharepoint API works with the received token. But when I want to display the frontend of that website (the HTML, aspx, ..., that what we can see in the browser), I get an "401 Unauthorized" error.

I can successfully retrieve a token for the user and a token to access the Sharepoint API. With the latter, I can query the Sharepoint API and receive a list of existing sites. This I display in a listview.

Besides that, I have an embedded browser which needs to show the selected Sharepoint site from that list. I mean by this the frontend of the website, that what we can see in the browser.

When loading the site URL in the embedded browser, I have to go through the login again. After that the site opens. If I add one of the tokens from above to the request (as a Bearer), I receive a "401 Unauthorized" back.

We already access other websites, which are behind an App registration in Azure, via that Bearer token in the request, so this way definitely works (we do use the scope user_impersonisation, which I can't find for Sharepoint online).

How can I access the Sharepoint frontend webpages from my application? Which scopes or tokens do I need for this? Or is this done via another way?

**Edit**

The scopes on the app registration are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/13q7H.png

First I create a public client app:

```
PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("[client id]")
.WithDefaultRedirectUri()
.WithDebugLoggingCallback(LogLevel.Error, true, true)
.WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "[TenantId]").Build();
```

Then I definde scopes and first request a token for the user interactively:

```
private static readonly string[] Scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
private static readonly string[] SharepointScopes = new string[] { "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/.default" };
```

```
AuthResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes).WithAccount(FirstAccount).ExecuteAsync();
AzureToken = AuthResult.AccessToken;
```

I succesfully receive a token and inspecting it gives me the same scopes as defined above:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZoTk.png

I then request a token silenty for the sharepoint scopes:

```
AuthResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(SharepointScopes, AuthResult.Account).ExecuteAsync();
                    SharepointAzureToken = AuthResult.AccessToken;
```

which is also succesful and giving the defined scope (I do note that there are 2 extra scopes, but can't figure why):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVylx.png

I use the token by overiding the "Authorization" header to "Bearer [token]" in the request handler of the browser (I use cefsharp).:

```
        protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            request.SetHeaderByName("Authorization", $"Bearer {MainWindowVM.SharepointAzureToken}", true);
            return CefReturnValue.Continue;
```

-> this certainly works, I use the same way to access other APIs that are also behind an App registration (custom, using the user_impersonation scope)

I point the browser to the URL of the site, https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSiteForRemoteManager, but get an 401 unauthorized page.

When I use the token to access the Sharepoint API via below code, the request succeeds and I get the data from the API. So it looks the token is just not working to display the frontend website.

```
            using (var context = new ClientContext(SharepointSite))
            {
                context.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
                {
                    e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + SharepointAzureToken;
                };

                var web = context.Web;
                context.Load(web);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                var Field = web.Fields;

                BrowserAddress = SharepointSite;
            }
```